# How to prevent adding same product to cart more than one time?

Tags: magento2, cart

As title says, how can I prevent adding same product to cart more than one time in Magento 2.4.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This plugin will work for simple and configurable products. You can throw an error or redirect e.g. to cart if product already exists in cart.

**di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
    <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Magento_Checkout_Cart_BeforeAddToCart" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Cart\BeforeAddToCart"/>
</type>
```

**vendor/module/Plugin/Magento/Checkout/Cart/BeforeAddToCart.php**

```
    <?php
    declare(strict_types=1);
    
    namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Checkout\Cart;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session\Proxy as SessionProxy;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\Product\Type\Configurable;
use Magento\Framework\UrlInterface;

class BeforeAddToCart {

    private $messageManager;
    private $cartSession;
    private $configurableProduct;
    private $url;
    private $session;

    public function __construct(
        Configurable $configurableProduct,
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        SessionProxy $cartSession,
        UrlInterface $url,
        Session $session
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->cartSession = $cartSession;
        $this->configurableProduct = $configurableProduct;
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->session = $session;
    }

    public function beforeAddProduct(Cart $subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo=null)
    {
        $enableProductCartControl=true;

        $product = null;
        $parentProduct=null;

        if ($productInfo instanceof Product) {

            $product = $productInfo;
            if (!$product->getId()) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __("This product wasn't found. Verify the product and try again.")
                );
            }

        }

        if ($product)
        {
            // default product is simple
            //
            if ($product->getTypeId()==='configurable')
            {
                if (isset($requestInfo['super_attribute']))
                {
                    $parentProduct=$product;
                    $childProduct = $this->configurableProduct->getProductByAttributes($requestInfo['super_attribute'] ,$product);
                    // change $product to child
                    $product=$childProduct;
                }
            }

                if ($product && $enableProductCartControl)
                {
                    // check for existence of product in cart...
                    if($this->cartSession->getQuote()->hasProductId($product->getId())){

                        // redirect to cart
                        $this->session->setRedirectUrl($this->url->getUrl('checkout/cart/index'));
                        throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                            __("[x] This product is already in the cart. Testing, testing : ". $product->getSku())
                        );
                    }

                }


        }

        return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];

    }

    /**
     * Get request for product add to cart procedure
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject|int|array $requestInfo
     * @return \Magento\Framework\DataObject
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     */
    private function _getProductRequest($requestInfo)
    {
        if ($requestInfo instanceof \Magento\Framework\DataObject) {
            $request = $requestInfo;
        } elseif (is_numeric($requestInfo)) {
            $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(['qty' => $requestInfo]);
        } elseif (is_array($requestInfo)) {
            $request = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($requestInfo);
        } else {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                __('We found an invalid request for adding product to quote.')
            );
        }
        return $request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tested it on my store which has only configurable products which all contain 2 simple products and 1 downloadable product inside, but it doesn't work. I cannot add any product to the cart anymore.

Comment: Check your logs for errors, the code works fine for me.

Comment: There's nothing on Magento logs. It simply refreshes the page but nothing is added to the cart.

Comment: You are implementing this in your own module right? You know "vendor/Module" should be replaced with your own module path?

Comment: Yes, I implemented it in my module. Yes, I replaced Vendor/Module with my own path.

Comment: OK, sorry I can't help further.

Comment: Tested again. My fault, I forgot to reboot Varnish server. It seems to work pretty well. Let me test it further.

Comment: How can I simply redirect to the cart (this is the default set behavior) once the product is added to the cart even if it's already added? I don't need to show any message.

Comment: I updated the answer with a cart redirect.

Comment: Do you mean this answer? https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/331655/13970

Comment: https://pastebin.com/ns3vSdFr

Comment: You commented out the throw error exception. It has to throw an error to stop the product being added.

Comment: Unfortunately nothing's changed after uncomment the throw error exception. It redirects, like before, to the cart page and shows the same message: `We can't add this item to your shopping cart right now.`

Comment: OK, it works fine for me.. I hope you can figure it out!

Comment: Do you mean it redirects to the cart without showing any error message and without adding 2 times the same product?

Comment: If it throws the error exception, how can it redirect after? I mean, when it throws the exception it goes out of the function. Could you please, paste your code here: https://pastebin.com/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120168/discussion-between-paj-and-kamzata).

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin for that

in you **di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart">
<plugin name="prevent_add_to" type="vendor\Module\Plugin\Beforeaddtocart"/>
</type>
```

**vendor\Module\Plugin\Beforeaddtocart.php**

```
<?php

namespace vendor\Module\Plugin;

class Beforeaddtocart{
    
    public function beforeAddProduct(\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo=null){
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $session = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Session');
        
        $product_id = $requestInfo['product'];
        $quote = $session->getQuote()->hasProductId($product_id);
        if($quote){
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __("The product is already in cart you can't add more than 1 qty")
                );
        }
        return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];

    }
}
```

**note:** Please don't use objectmanager directly

Comment: This code will not work for variations of configurable products added to cart.

Comment: Thanks, but since my store has only configurable products which contain 2 simple products and 1 downloadable product, how can I adapt it in order to prevent to add just 1 kind of these products and not the whole configurable product?

Comment: Anyway, it seems to work for the whole configurable product (but not for the child, as I wrote)

Comment: sorry the code was not tested. but yes that code not work for configurable product